# Open new tab on button click using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My Scenario is this:

I have edit user module. Each user has been allocated a **Base INI File**.
When we edit a user, we have a dropdown from which we select a his **Base INI File**

After selection we may save the user. and the id of selected file is also saved.

> This is working fine.

But, when we edit a user i have an option to let user make a `custom_ini_file`. So when he clicks on the edit button code copies the content from one file and creates a new file and let user make custom changes in that and then that file will be saved.

Now i want to open this edit `custom_ini_file` in new tab or windows and keep the user edit page open. 
Once he completes editing the file then and only then he can go back to editing user and save users as well.

So basically he should be able to edit a user and a file.

Now in edit user i have a dropdown like this along with edit button:

```
<tr>
    <td>Base INI File</td>
    <?php 

        if(isset($_GET['id'])) { 
            $id=$_GET['id']; 
            btn_edit($id); 
        } 
    ?>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


    <td> 
        <select required name="base_ini_id" id="base_ini_id" class="form-control"> 
            <option value="">Select</option> 
            <?php foreach($base as $value) { ?> 
                <option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>"><?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;?></option> 
            <?php } ?> 
        </select> 
    </td> 
    <td> 
        <?php echo btn_edit('customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_custom/'); ?> 
    </td> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#base_ini_id').change(function() { 
                var id = $("#base_ini_id").val();
                var url = "/project/customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_custom/";

                $("#edit_link").attr("href",url+ id); 

            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
</tr>
```

**Edit Button**

```
function btn_edit ($uri)
{
    return anchor($uri, '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>','id="edit_link"');
}
```

Comment: edit_link this id is missing please check

Comment: @SRK i have defined that button in helpers i will post it as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In helper

```
 anchor($uri, '<i class="glyphicon gl yphicon-edit"></i>','id="edit_link"');
```

Replace this with following it will work

```
 anchor($uri, '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>',array('id'=>"edit_link", 'target'=> '_blank');
```

in jquery

```
$("#edit_link").attr("target","_blank");
```

Comment: this does the task but how to get the id back to edit user method?? i mean how will i know which file was created? is there any way?

Comment: $this->uri->segment(n) this will help to get id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105076/discussion-between-srk-and-rajan).